# Multiple Media Files (Audio/Video/Image) sharing on WhatsApp

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6

I want to know that how to share multiple media files on what app.
Please guid me if there is already same question available.
Here is the code i'm using for Text,

```
- (void)WhatsAppClicked
{
    NSString *textwithTitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@\n\n%@",LS_detailTitleLabel.text,LS_detailTextView.text];
    NSString *textURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whatsapp://send?text=%@",textwithTitle];//make string
    textURL=[textURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];//now make string look like URL
    NSURL *whatsappURL = [NSURL URLWithString:textURL];//now pass it into URL
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: whatsappURL])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: whatsappURL];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp Error...!" message:@"WhatsApp Might not installed on your phone.Install it and try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

this code perfectly works for sending text.
thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to share your image

Here image_share is your image which you want to share

```
-(void)whatsappShare
{
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"whatsapp://app"]])
{
    UIImage *iconImage = image_share;
    NSString * savePath  = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/whatsAppTmp.wai"];

    [UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iconImage, 1.0) writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];

    _documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:savePath]];
    _documentInteractionController.UTI = @"net.whatsapp.image";
    _documentInteractionController.delegate = self;

    [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0) inView:self.view animated: YES];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"WhatsApp not installed." message:@"Please Install WhatsApp Application to share" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue",nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

Comment: Please, provide guidance on multiple sharing.

Comment: sorry vats, i don't have any idea about that